Real Analysis, series and sequences
For a convergent series of non-negative terms, is the sequence of partial sums upper bounded by the value of the series? By definition of convergence of series, can I immediately conclude such a statement?

Have you tried thinking about it? Please add your attempt and your thoughts, otherwise, the question will get closed.

I've thought about it, but I'm not sure. If the series of non-negative terms is convergent then the sequence of partial sums is bounded and is also increasing and converges to the supreme, but the fact is that I believe that the supreme is not necessarily the value of the convergent series.

Yes, the sum of  a convergent series with non-negative terms is the Supremum of the sequence of partial sums, i.e. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N^+}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k.$$

The definition is: a series converges iff the sequence of partial sums converge.

Let's start with a definition of a convergent series. We say $S_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i$ converges to some limit $l$ if :
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \left(\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \left(\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \left(n \geq N \implies |S_n - l| < \varepsilon \right)\right)\right)$$
Suppose the partial sums weren't bounded by the limit of the series $l$.
Then there exists $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $S_M =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{M}a_i > l.$
Since the series contains only non-negative values we have $S_n \ge S_M \space\space\forall n \ge M$.
Let $\varepsilon = S_M - l \gt 0$
Then $\forall n \ge M, |S_n - l| \gt \varepsilon$
Hence, we have found an $\varepsilon$ which contradicts the definition of convergence.
i.e $\exists \varepsilon \gt 0 \left(\forall N \in \mathbb{N}\left(\exists n \in \mathbb{N}\left(n \ge N : |S_n - l| \gt \varepsilon\right)\right)\right)$
